# Android - Get Selected Item from Dynamically created Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I create a Spinner depending on some rules of my app. So, its created dynamically. How can I retrieve which item was selected?

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)linearMoreInfo.getChildAt(1);
```

Using this code to retrieve the created dynamically spinner. But got no idea of how I can handle its click/select item.

Any helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it works for you:

```
   mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
        {           
            Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            ...         
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }    
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code...

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selected_item_position = pos;
                selected_item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                // You can insert your code...
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```